# Cannot link local libraries in CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, linker, libraries

I'm developing a c++ program on visual studio that will be deployed on linux, and it is debugged on linux through an ssh. Currently, this is the structure of my folder:

```
ANT
-xscommon
--xscommon_config.h
-xscontroller
-xstypes
ANT.cpp
ANT.h
CMakeLists.txt
CMakeSettings.json
hashes.h
quaternionic.h
stars.h
```

Currently, all the `.h, .cpp, .o, .cpp.o, .a` files that I think I have to link to are kept within the three xs------- directories. I am quite new to cmake, and this linking to these libraries is giving me trouble; I am able to link correctly to the includes, but there are undefined references errors thrown when I don't do linking, and when I attempt linking, it throws errors. This is my current CMakeLists.txt file:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for ANT, include source and define
# project specific logic h"ere.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("ANT")

link_directories(${ANT_SOURCE_DIR}/xscommon xscontroller xstypes)

add_executable(
    ANT
    "ANT.cpp" 
    "ANT.h" 
    "quaternionic.h" 
    "stars.h"
    "hashes.h"
)

target_include_directories(ANT PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(ANT PUBLIC xscommon_config)
```

When I run this, the builder says the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxscommon_config
```

I need to look for these libraries in the directory that ANT.cpp is in, as this is where they are kept, however nothing I do (and I have messed around with configurations for hours now) will tell camke to look for these libraries in the src folder. it always goes to `/usr/bin/ld`.

I really just need to know what to tell CMake such that it will look in the correct place for each file, that is if I am telling it to look for the correct file (I am fairly sure I am).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Update

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

So I have remade the CMakeLists.txt file to this:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for ANT, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.15)

project ("ANT")

#[STATIC | SHARED | MODULE]
#[STATIC | SHARED | MODULE]
#[STATIC | SHARED | MODULE]


add_library(xscommon SHARED IMPORTED)
add_library(xscontroller SHARED IMPORTED)
add_library(xstypes SHARED IMPORTED)

add_executable(
    ANT
    "ANT.cpp" 
    "ANT.h" 
)

target_include_directories(ANT PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

And still get undefined references. I am going to try building the libraries instead. Additionally, I have contacted the manufacturer of the IMUs which use this SDK, as colleagues have not been able to fix this either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're trying to link pre-built external libraries to your `ANT` executable, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library) question and its responses for proper methods for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are linking to a library that has not been build.
This

```
# link to this directory
target_link_libraries(ANT PRIVATE xscommon)
```

tries to link to a library called xscommon to the target ANT but you have not build xscommon anywhere in your project.

If xscommon is a pre-build library and you just want to import it then add the library and set the IMPORTED target property:

```
add_library(xscommon [STATIC | SHARED | MODULE] IMPORTED)
```

If you want to build xscommon in your root CMakeLists.txt. Add xscommon as a library and include the location of the headers.

```
add_library(xscommon [STATIC | SHARED | MODULE]
    xxx/xxx.cpp #list all source files that build the library - use relative path
)
target_include_directories(xscommon PRIVATE
   xxx/xxx #path to the location of library header files
)
```

Also you don't need to add the header files when adding the executable. So this

```
add_executable(
    ANT
    "ANT.cpp" 
    "ANT.h" 
    "quaternionic.h" 
    "stars.h"
    "hashes.h"
)
```

can be simplified to

```
add_executable(
    ANT
    "ANT.cpp" 
)
```

Comment: I attempted the first option, with without any decent luck, still undefined references. I am attempting the build option.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your dir is like this:

```
ANT
-xscommon
--xscommon_config.h
--xscommon_config.cpp
...
```

First add a `CMakeLists.txt` file to `xscommon/`:

```
ANT
-xscommon
--CMakeLists.txt
--xscommon_config.h
--xscommon_config.cpp
...
```

Now in `xscommon/CMakeLists.txt` we will create a library, that will be imported and linked in the main CMakeLists.txt file:

**xscommon/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
#define another target, let's name it 'xscommon'
add_library(xscommon
   xscommon_config.h
   xscommon_config.cpp
   #more sources if you want
   )
```

Now in the main `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("ANT")

#remove this line
#link_directories(${ANT_SOURCE_DIR}/xscommon xscontroller xstypes)

add_executable(
    ANT
    "ANT.cpp" 
    "ANT.h" 
    "quaternionic.h" 
    "stars.h"
    "hashes.h"
)

# add the xscommon directory, this will make the library target defined there available here
add_subdirectory(xscommon)

# link to this directory
target_link_libraries(ANT PRIVATE xscommon)
# use PUBLIC if the xscommon library will be part of the public interface of your
# library. But since it is an executable, PRIVATE is better here.

target_include_directories(ANT PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Use the above method, you can create more libraries and link to them.

Note that it is not *necessary* to create separate cmake files for each subdirectory but it is considered a good practice and modularizes your code. If you want to do this in the main cmake file instead of creating a subdirectory, add this to the main cmake:

```
add_library(xscommon
   xscommon/xscommon_config.h
   xscommon/xscommon_config.cpp
   #more sources if you want
   )
```

---

### Update according to the changes in question

Your current `CMakeLists.txt`:

These three lines below are not doing anything, definitely not what you think. `add_library()` command has the word "add" in it, I know, but it doesn't add any library, just like `add_executable` doesn't add any executable. It *creates* a library.

```
add_library(xscommon SHARED IMPORTED)
add_library(xscontroller SHARED IMPORTED)
add_library(xstypes SHARED IMPORTED)
```

How to create a library in cmake out of two file `a.cpp` and `a.h`:

```
add_library(myALib "a.cpp")
```

That's it. If you have more sources, you will include them accordingly of course. In your case you will have to add the sources of `xscommon` and others accordingly.

Once you have created the libraries, you need to *link* them to your executable. If you won't you will get *undefined reference* errors because compiler can locate the declarations in header files but not the definitions of your code which exists in `.cpp` files.

So, how do you link? Simple:

```
target_link_libraries(TARGET_NAME PUBLIC | PRIVATE LIBRARY_NAME)
# TARGET_NAME: can be `executable` or `library`
# PUBLIC or PRIVATE (for exe, it is usually private)
# LIBRARY_NAME: Name of library you want to link to TARGET_NAME

# So if you wanted to link "myALib" which I created above to ANT, you would do:
target_link_libraries(ANT PRIVATE myALib)

# Note: You need to add this line **after** add_executable() because target "ANT" will be created after that. You can do the linking after the "target_include_directories" command.
```

Comment: For each of the folders with a new CMakeLists.txt it says this:
```
1> [CMake] CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "ixscommon".
1> [CMake] CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: xscommon
```
or some variant. It seemingly treats the library name as a link. If I remove link from CMakeLists.txt, it says the same thing, but for xscommon_config.h

Comment: do you have `.cpp` files in `xscommon`? If not, then it is futile to make a library out of it.

Comment: can you update the question, to add the changes you made (separately), so that I can see what you did exactly? and if possible, maybe show the files that are in `xscommon`?

Comment: Will do. I have used the advice from the comment below this, though it does not seem to want to work that way either.

Comment: Just saw your updated cmake, that won't work definitely. I will update the answer

Comment: I updated the answer assuming you have the source code of `xscommon` and other libs. If they are prebuilt, you just need the last part `target_link_libraries`, where `LIBRARY_NAME` will be the `PATH + lib name`. So, if lib name is `libxscommon.a`, you will write `target_link_libraries(ANT PRIVATE xscommon/xscommon)`. CMake will add `lib` prefix automatically.